# How to convert time from CEST to UTC in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

How I can convert "23-08-2012 00:00:00 CEST" to UTC format in flex?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your date is a string, you can use the DateFormatter to convert it to a Date type and then get UTC time from there:

```
var date:Date = DateFormatter.parseDateString(dateString);
date.getUTCDate();
```

You can see all the UTC functions at the [Date API reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html).